# Setting mocked method return value when called with specific parameters

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-3.x, mocking

I have a test that works by mocking out the web service. I have it where it returns a specific return value when a specific method is called. I'm verifying that the wrapped function returns the value I expect. Issue is that the test seems almost useless.

Here is what I have -

```
@patch('run.Client')
def test(self, mock_client):
    service = WebService()
    mock_client.return_value.service.GetMemberStatus.return_value = 'E'
    member_status = service.get_member_status(11)
    self.assertEqual('E', member_status)
```

What I'm looking to do is only return `E` if the `GetMemberStatus` method is called with specific parameters. I've tried to do -

```
mock_client.return_value.service.GetMemberStatus(11, '', '').return_value = 'E'
```

however this doesn't seem to change anything.

Question - How can I set a mocked methods return value only if called with appropriate parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking, you don't. You instead assert that your mocked method has been called with the expected parameters as part of your test:

```
gms_mock = mock_client.return_value.service.GetMemberStatus
gms_mock.return_value = 'E'

member_status = service.get_member_status(11)

self.assertEqual('E', member_status)
gms_mock.assert_called_with(11, '', '')
```

All your attempt did was record a mock call, as if the code-under-test had called `GetMemberStatus`, then assigned `'E'` on the `return_value` attribute of the `Mock` instance returned by that call.

You *could* set the [`side_effect` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.side_effect) to a function instead; it'll be passed the arguments and you could test there:

```
def gms_mock_call(*args):
    assert args == (11, '', '')
    return 'E'

mock_client.return_value.service.GetMemberStatus.side_effect = gms_mock_call
```

but that really puts testing what arguments are passed in in the wrong location.

Comment: Thank you for the answer as well as alternative ways. I poured over mocking documentations, but wasn't looking for the right terms. In addition, I found you can replace the `gms_mock_call` method with a lambda - `gms_mock.side_effect = lambda *args: 'E' if args == (11, '', '') else None`. Not sure how I feel about that, though. Will have to play with it.

Comment: Turns out `pep8` throws error `E731` if you assign a lambda expression. Thanks again.